# Parameterizing the binary operation when combining two lists

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a program that takes in two lists and a binary operation and takes each element of one list and applies it to the other using the binary operation. I have it working but not sure how to change it so it works with *any* binary operator. Here's examples :

```
myFunction (+) [100,200,300] [4,3,2,1] would return
[96,97,98,99,196,197,198,199,296,297,298,299]

myFunction (+) [100,200,300] [4,3,2,1] would return
[96,97,98,99,196,197,198,199,296,297,298,299]
```

This is what I have working with specific binary operations

```
oneEle :: Char -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
oneEle a x [] = []
oneEle a x y
    | (a == '+') = [p + x | p <- y]
    | (a == '-') = [p - x | p <- y]
    | (a == '*') = [p * x | p <- y]
    | (a == ':') = [p * x | p <- y]
    
myFunction :: Char -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
myFunction a [] [] = []
myFunction a [] y = []
myFunction a x [] = []
myFunction a (x:xs) (y:ys) = oneEle a x ([y] ++ ys) ++ myFunction a xs ([y]++ys)
```

Comment: When I try replace the plus symbol in "[p + x | p <- y]" with the character it gives an error.

Comment: Two small remarks: both your examples are the same and please post code as code, not as a picture.

Comment: When you pass an operator as a function, you apply that function in prefix form, like `f x y`, not in infix form, like `x f y`

Comment: Post code as text *in* the question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: That said, you appear to be reimplementing the `Applicative` instance for `[]`; look at `liftA2 (-) [100, 200, 300] [4, 3, 2 ,1]`, for example.

Comment: @chepner I think that might be the point of the exercise.

Comment: 1. Your `':'` case uses `*` as operation, 2. your two examples are the same, 3. your `(+)` example seems to compute `-`, 4. your code uses `Char` but your example uses a binary function (which would be of type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`), 5. what if the lists are of different size?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann This isn't a zip; differently-sized lists don't need special handling.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is a list comprehension:

```
myFunction f xs ys = [f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

It may not even be worth defining a new function; instead, just inline that content to the call site.

This function is also available from the standard library by the names `liftM2` and `liftA2`.